# Поиск в массиве и вывод в уведомление

Tags: java, android, массивы, activity

Помогите с массивом. Например- есть int массив с числами 
a[]={10-15,20-25,30-35} 
10-15,20-25,30-35-это диапазоны чисел, может я не правильно записал ? ..Мне нужно чтобы в этом массиве искало  число в том числе и в диапазонах этих чисел. Например число 13
                         .........  {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int[] number = {500-550,600-650,700-750,800-850};

    if(contains(number, 630)){
        System.out.println("yes");
    }

}

public static boolean contains(final int[] array, final int v) {

    boolean result = false;

    for(int i : array){
        if(i == v){
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: Кхм, кхм. Как далеко Вы продвинулись самостоятельно?

Comment: Ну с диапазонами я ничего не встречал похожего, может я не так ищу , записываю свою мысль..

Comment: А Вы рассчитывали писать только такой код, какой Вы встречали раньше?

Comment: Да такой ,  может можно как двухмерн массив ,[][]- ?много чисел...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[] number = {500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850};

if(contains(number, 630)){
    System.out.println("yes");
}


public static boolean contains(final int[] array, final int v) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 2) {
    if (v >= array[i] && v <= array[i + 1])
        return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Помогло) спасибо , то что нужно буду дальше идти к цели.

Comment: @Pasha Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.